# VPN between 2 windows servers

Tags: windows, iis, vpn

I have an application that runs on a remote server (server A). Specifically, it is a virtual windows server I rent from fasthosts. In order to work, it needs to read data from a file which is stored on that server about the current status of a server I have in-house.

This in-house server (server B) has a service running on it which is meant to update that file with the specified data. We are thinking this can be done with VPN.

Previously, they were both on local servers and so had no trouble communicating (we simply mapped the folder on server A to server B). We have been forced to, as aforementioned, migrate server A to a remote server, and need VPN to do this.

I do not know much about VPN, so can anyone give any guidance as to exactly how this is done?

Both servers run Windows Server 2008 & IIS.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [RRAS to create an SSTP VPN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655) between your servers.

"Halp! Hold mah hand thru this" is out of the scope of this site, but the linked document provides step-by-step details of how to set up a test environment for this.

Alternatively, you could use a VPN termination point at each site to create a site-to-site VPN between the two locations. Most firewalls worth their salt will be able to do this and it will allow you to scale out more effectively if you end up needing more servers at the remote site, since you won't have to configure the VPN on each remote machine.